# Is there a next permutation in Java?

Tags: java

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream> 
  
using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    string s = { "gfg" }; 
    bool val 
        = next_permutation(s.begin(), 
                           s.end()); 
    if (val == false) 
        cout << "No Word Possible"
             << endl; 
    else
        cout << s << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

As you can see in the code, there is a next permutation function in c++. more on the next permutation function code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-next-lexicographically-greater-word-than-a-given-word/).
However, I want to know if there is a similar function in Java.

Comment: No, have [a look for yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: It looks like there are [various](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/06/leetcode-next-permutation-java/) other [ports](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/06/leetcode-next-permutation-java/), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no inbuilt function in Java for the next_permutation.
But you can use this as I use this in codeforces contests.

```
boolean next_permutation(int[] p) {
  for (int a = p.length - 2; a >= 0; --a)
    if (p[a] < p[a + 1])
      for (int b = p.length - 1;; --b)
        if (p[b] > p[a]) {
          int t = p[a];
          p[a] = p[b];
          p[b] = t;
          for (++a, b = p.length - 1; a < b; ++a, --b) {
            t = p[a];
            p[a] = p[b];
            p[b] = t;
          }
          return true;
        }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The absence in Java something like C++ `next_permutation`/`prev_permutation` inspired me to add Java implementation to the Maven Central

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hextriclosan</groupId>
    <artifactId>algorithm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The algorithm implemented as an iterator. Sample code like

```
var iterator = new NextPermutationIterator<>(List.of('A', 'B', 'B'));
iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

prints out

```
[A, B, B]
[B, A, B]
[B, B, A]
```